# 3-4 second delays in discord.js messages

Tags: node.js

There is a 2-3 second delay in each message, including message listeners.
I use one message listener, I made analysis and when a message is sent or a command is used, RAM and CPU usage reaches a very high amount, but I do not know the reason.

I am using 2 Bots using classes.
I think there is a leak but I have no idea where it is. How can I find the problem?
I would also like to add this when I send the command or message, I can immediately get a response from the Console.

There was more than 1 message listener and I placed them all in one listener but it didn't work.